# error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'KnockoutExtenders'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, knockout-3.0

I try to use knockout in TypeScript and I think I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33013634/property-isvalid-does-not-exist-on-type-knockoutobservable) but I can't find the typings that I need to install. The code line is:

```
ko.extenders.name = function (target : string) {
```

and error is:

```
error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'KnockoutExtenders'.
```

How can I fix this?

Further errors of the same type in my code are:

```
error TS2339: Property 'number' does not exist on type 'KnockoutExtenders'.
```

and

```
error TS2339: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.
```

for code

```
$('#signup-dialog').modal('show');
```

Comment: Looks like knockoutjs `KnockoutExtenders` type doesn't have a `name`, nor `number` property [@types/knockoutjs](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5309ec5061017977ac5a2b10bf90e91870d60b4c/types/knockout/index.d.ts#L457). For `.modal` you definetely need to import a specific [plugin](https://jquerymodal.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `.modal()` came from Bootstrap. So I had to install bootstrap typings via `npm install --save-dev @types/bootstrap`.